# Running pytest.main twice from the same python script

Tags: pytest

I have script which run pytest.main twice.
There is a test which needs to be run in each session with different parametrized values
In parametrizing decorator i use function get_time:

```
import datetime
import pytest

def get_time():
    time_list = [datetime.datetime.now().second,
                 datetime.datetime.now().second + 1]
    return time_list

@pytest.mark.parametrize('time',get_time())
def test_1(time):
    print(time)
```

The main script as follows:

```
import pytest

sq = ["--collect-only",  # Here are pytest flags
      rx_setup_tests/test_twice_parametrize.py::test_1",
      ]
pytest.main(sq)

sq = ["--collect-only",  # Here are pytest flags
      rx_setup_tests/test_twice_parametrize.py::test_1",
      ]
pytest.main(sq)
```

The function get_time is called only once and the parameterized arguments stay the same in the second session.

Please your advice

Thank you very much, Nadav

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case of [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/): you are describing an attempted solution, but not your actual goal.

What are you trying to achieve here?

> I have script which run pytest.main twice.

Why is that? Is it just to run this test with more parametrizations, or are there other reasons and this should just be considered a given?

Also, usually you want to avoid having tests based on "current time" since they are not reproducible nor deterministic. If, for instance, you have those tests as part of a build pipeline, that pipeline might fail at some point unexpectedly. In other words, the fact that the test passes "now" doesn't guarantee that it will pass in the future. This is usually not desirable.

If you are trying to get better coverage / test against more values of `dt.datetime`, you have several options:

1. parametrize the function with more values specified manually (assuming you know which values might be tricky)
2. generate pseudo-random values
3. use a library such as [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/) that will generate all sorts of values for you

For case 2 above, you can do something like

```py
import random

random.seed(0)

def generate_time_values(n) -> list[dt.datetime]:
    """
    Generate uniformly distributed random datetimes
    in the `[anchor, anchor + time_range]` interval.
    """
    # This is arbitrary. If you want coverage across timezones,
    # I highly recommend using hypothesis.
    anchor = dt.datetime(2024, 1, 1)
    # This is also up to you
    time_range = dt.timedelta(days=365)
    return [anchor + random.random() * time_range for i in range(n)]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("time", generate_time_values(100))
def test_time(time: dt.datetime):
    print(time)
```